# AngularJS : Two-Way Binding an Unknown Property Inside a Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've built a directive that basically creates a markdown-friendly text editor. It will be used at various places throughout my site, anywhere an end user wants to use markdown to do some basic content styling (product descriptions, that sort of thing). The challenge is that as this directive will be deployed in multiple places, it won't be editing the same property on every model. For example, in one spot it may edit the LongDescription of a product, whereas in another spot it may edit the ShortDescription of an ad campaign, or the Bio of a user.

I need to be able to pass in the property that I want to edit to the directive using the scope '=' method that permits two-way data binding, so the property is changed both in the directive and on the original controller, allowing the user to save those changes. The problem that I'm having is that if I pass the property itself to the directive:

```
<markdown-editor model="product.Description"></markdown-editor>
```

two-way data binding doesn't work, since this passes the value of the Description property. I know that for the '=' method to two-way bind in a directive, I have to pass an object as the attribute value from my HTML. I can easily pass the entire object:

```
<markdown-editor model="product"></markdown-editor>
```

and then access the Description property within the directive:

```
<textarea ng-model="model.Description"></textarea>
```

but this hardcodes Description into the directive, and I may not always want that property.

So my question is, how can I two-way bind to a single property of my object, without the directive knowing ahead of time what that property is? I've come up with a workaround but it's pretty ugly:

HTML:

```
<markdown-editor model="contest" property="Description"></markdown-editor>
```

Directive JS:

```
angular.module('admin.directives').directive('markdownEditor', [
    'admin.constants.templateConstants',
    '$sce',
    function (Templates, $sce) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: Templates.Directives.MarkdownEditor,
            scope: {
                model: '=',
                property: '@'
            },
            controllerAs: 'markdownEditor',
            controller: markdownEditorController
        }

        function markdownEditorController($scope) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.display = { markdown: true };
            vm.content = { markdown: '', html: '' }; 

            console.log($scope.model);

            vm.setDisplay = function (type) {
                vm.display = {};
                vm.display[type] = true;
            }

            $scope.$watch('model', function (newModel, oldModel, $scope) {
                vm.content.markdown = $scope.model[$scope.property];
            });

            $scope.$watch('markdownEditor.content.markdown', function (newDescription, oldDescription, $scope) {
                $scope.model[$scope.property] = newDescription;
                if (newDescription !== "" && newDescription !== null && newDescription !== undefined) {
                    vm.content.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(marked(newDescription));
                }
            });
        }

        return directive;
    }
]);
```

Relevant part of the directive template:

```
<textarea class="ad-basic-input" ng-model="markdownEditor.content.markdown" ng-if="markdownEditor.display.markdown"></textarea>
```

Notice that the directive uses a watch to look for changes on the content.markdown field, then pushes those back into model[property] manually (the second $watch near the bottom). It also has to $watch for changes to the model being passed in from the controller above because that's being loaded asynchronously, and needs to be assigned to the content.markdown field initially.

This code works, but having these two watches, especially the one that looks for changes on the model, seems like a big code smell to me. Surely there must be a better way to pass in, edit, and two-way bind a single property of an object on the controller, when that property is unknown?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't "two way" data bind primitive data types, read [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: I know I can't do that directly, which is why I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: What you should do is change your object structure which contains different types of your model name and an endpoint with same property `content` so you'll use the same endpoint in your template.